# Multiple search elements

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I am stuck when it comes to adding more than one search element. I can get 1 search element to work using the [Fusion tables layer wizard](http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/fusiontables/fusiontableslayer_builder.html) but any others added don't function? My website is called [earthquakedamagemap.com](http://earthquakedamagemap.com). I'm trying to build a similar search function to that of newspapermap.com

It is my university project. Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you add some more details? What doesn't work? Have you used Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools to look for error messages? If so, what are they?

Comment: The search queries don't work. Well only the top one does. I'm looking for error messages now. cheers

Comment: errors: Server configuration - Issues found. This site returns "soft 404" errors for missing pages, which means a success status code is returned for non-existent pages. This means some broken links cannot be detected on this site.

Comment: all your buttons point to http://www.earthquakedamagemap.com/date.html which doesn't exist. So you need to create a page for those to go to, or create a JS function that does the search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the id of your second select menu to search-string1. Then, in your changeMap1 function, pass 'search-string1' to the method document.getElementById().

Comment: Amazing Kathryn! Thank you. Now I need to get the search functions to cooperate together, as a filter system. You've saved me!